# MySQL How to display a column info of a given table?

Tags: mysql

[SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html) displays information about all the columns of a given table. But how can i display one particular column only or some columns?

Comment: what information do you want to display?

Comment: I just want 1 row returned instead of 5 rows shown in the [first example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` clasue

```
SHOW  COLUMNS FROM `table_name` WHERE `field` ='your columns name'
```

or you can use `LIKE`

```
SHOW  COLUMNS FROM `table_name` WHERE `field` LIKE '%your columns name%'
```

[**As docs already defined**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html)

[**Sample fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/23477)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system tables directly

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your_table'
and column_name = 'some_column_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as an example

```
Select columnname From table LIMIT 1
```